# crudbooster, insert data with my query in admincontroller before_add function

Tags: php, laravel, crudbooster

I just made a module and menu about user data. In the controller, i made a laravel query to insert into my database table inside hook_before_add function. The problem is, after I hit the save button, the controller insert 2 records.
Is it possible to use only my query to insert? 
Because All I need to do is to use my own laravel query to insert into my table because I need encrypt the password field with my custom encryption function(my company's standard password encryption) there. Can anyone help me, please?

```
 public function hook_before_add(&$postdata) {        
        //Your code here

        $password = Request::get('password');

        DB::table('user_personal')->insert([
            'email'=> Request::get('email'),
            'password'=> '',//$this->myencryptionfunction($password),
            'fullname'=> Request::get('fullname'),
            'phone'=> Request::get('phone'),
            'company'=> Request::get('company'),
            'status'=> Request::get('status'),
            'created_at'=> now()
        ]);

        //return Route::get('/admin/users');
        return Route::redirect('/admin/users', true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use:

```
public function hook_before_add(&$postdata) {        

    $password = Request::get('password');

    DB::table('user_personal')->insert([
        'email'=> Request::get('email'),
        'password'=> $this->myencryptionfunction($password);
        'fullname'=> Request::get('fullname'),
        'phone'=> Request::get('phone'),
        'company'=> Request::get('company'),
        'status'=> Request::get('status'),
        'created_at'=> now()
    ]);

    //return Route::get('/admin/users');
    return Route::redirect('/admin/users', true);

}
```